# Wordpress MyCred API-Page not found "404"

Tags: php, wordpress, api, e-commerce

I am trying to get myCred's API to work but it seems the "api page" that i have set in the settings is not reachable.

My request responses look like this:

```
Array ( [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( [date] => Sat, 13 May 2017 15:22:07 GMT [server] => Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) [content-length] => 282 [content-type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 ) ) [body] =>
Not Found
The requested URL /api-dev/ was not found on this server.
```

Using a browser to reach the site also leads to a "404 Page not found" response

Does anyone have an idea where i could have made a mistake? Thanks in advance!